# Sequelize pagination

Tags: node.js, pagination, sequelize.js

Using `sequelize` on my `nodejs` web app, I want to query posts using pagination (by date). Reading [`sequelize` docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#pagination-limiting), they offer to use `offset` and `limit`.

Since I want to display the posts from new to old, I need to consider the date they were created. For example, if I limit the first query to 10 page, and before executing the second query a new post was created, the next query with offset of 10 will result a duplicate post from the last query.

How should I implement the pagination so it will support new entries?

Answer (score 61):

The easiest way to do this is to use Sequelize's `findAndCountAll`

```
Post.findAndCountAll({
    where: {...},
    order: [...],
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0,
}).then(function (result) {
    res.render(...);
});
```

Here, result has both the result of your query and count as `result.rows` and `result.count`. You can then increment the offset and use this for pagination.

[Sequelize documentation for `findAndCountAll`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAndCountAll)

Comment: There's also a `findAndCount` helper method which will return the count of items based off this but not the items themselves.

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `findAndCountAll` if you only want to do pagination - `findAll` also supports the `limit` and `offset` parameters.

Comment: @ZachBloomquist , but how would you know how many pages you have?

Comment: @Ioanna see the linked docs - `res.result` will contain the total number of matching rows, while `res.rows` will contain the rows limited by `limit` and `offset`

Comment: Yes, if you use `findAndCountAll`. But in your comment you said `findAll` could also be used for pagination. Indeed, `findAll` also accepts a `limit` and an `offset` params, i'm not sure these are enough for pagination. Wouldn't you also need the `rows` that only `findAndCountAll` provides?

Comment: `findAll` is not sufficient because you need the total number of items in order to calculate the total number of pages. So you need the `findAndCountAll` and send both the `.rows` and the `.count`.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
const paginate = (query, { page, pageSize }) => {
  const offset = page * pageSize;
  const limit = pageSize;

  return {
    ...query,
    offset,
    limit,
  };
};


model.findAll(
  paginate(
    {
      where: {}, // conditions
    },
    { page, pageSize },
  ),
);
```

In order to avoid boilerplate code

Answer (score 18):

If you want to have a stable pagination, don't paginate on row offset, since it's volatile, for the reason you mention.

You should aim for paginating on a value that is stable over time and use a where clause for filtering results. The best case would be if you have an auto-incrementing id, but the post date could also be reasonable.

Something like:

```js
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    createdDate: {
      $lt: previousDate,
    },
  },
  limit: 10,
});
```

You need to keep track of previousDate for this ofc. This approach also has some caveats, and you may need to combine it with client-side de-duplication.

Here is a blog post that probably has all the answers you need:
[Pagination: You're (Probably) Doing It Wrong](https://coderwall.com/p/lkcaag/pagination-you-re-probably-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: What if I want to sort posts by its likes and paginate, can't use date in that case right?

Answer (score 16):

**With `findAndCountAll`** here count is useful for pagination, from this total count we can limit as we want and also with async and await

```js
let resAccidents = await ModalName.findAndCountAll({
  where: { createdByID: employeeID },
  offset: 0,
  limit: 10,
});
```

this will return a count of total records as per where condition and 1st 10 records of it, then increase the value of offset to fetch further records.

Comment: For retrieve all just set 
    offset: null,
    limit: null

Comment: Does this actually count all the documents or does it use count estimate internally?

Comment: This should be recommeded use while using datatables at the frontend (Y)

Answer (score 10):

You can simply do that

```js
let limit = 10;
let offset = 0 + (req.body.page - 1) * limit;
Posts.findAndCountAll({
  offset: offset,
  limit: limit,
  order: [["date", "ASC"]],
})
  .then(async (result) => {
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      message: res.__("success"),
      innerData: result,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return validator.InvalidResponse(res, `${err}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
db.findAll({
   offset: page_no,// your page number
      limit:25,// your limit
```

Comment: findAndCountAll method will help to count total data count

Comment: This also helpful if we don't want total count.

Answer (score 1):

This one solved my issue.

```
export const paginate = (query, schema) => {
  let page = query.page ? query.page - 1 : 0;
  page = page < 0 ? 0 : page;
  let limit = parseInt(query.limit || 10);
  limit = limit < 0 ? 10 : limit;
  const offset = page * limit;
  const where = {};
  delete query.page;
  delete query.limit;
  Object.keys(schema).forEach((key) => {
    schema[key] && query[key] ? (where[key] = query[key]) : null;
  });
  return {
    where: where,
    offset,
    limit,
  };
};

@Get()
findAll(@Query() query): unknown {
  return this.model.findAll(paginate(query, {xx:1}));
}
```

/model?xx=yy&page=1&limit=5

Answer (score -1):

```js
var defered = Q.defer();
const offset = queryString.offset * queryString.limit;
const limit = queryString.limit;
var queryWhere = { class_id: { $ne: null }, section_id: { $ne: null } };
var searchClass = {};
var searchSection = {};
if (queryString) {
    if (queryString.class && queryString.class !== "") {
       searchClass = { class_id: { $eq: queryString.class } };
    } else if (queryString.class && queryString.class === "") {
       searchClass = { class_id: { $ne: null } };
    }

if (queryString.section && queryString.section !== "") {
      searchSection = { section_id: { $eq: queryString.section } };
} else if (queryString.section && queryString.section === "") {
      searchSection = { section_id: { $ne: null } };
}
}

queryWhere = {
    $and: [[searchClass], [searchSection]]
};
const schoolDB = require("../../db/models/tenant")(schema);
const Student = schoolDB.model("Student");
Student.findAll({
   attributes: [
  "id",
  "first_name",
  "last_name",
  "profile_image_url",
  "roll_number",
  "emergency_contact_number"
],
offset: offset,
limit: limit,
where: queryWhere,
order: [["roll_number", "ASC"]]
})
.then(result => {
  defered.resolve(result);
})
.catch(err => {
  defered.reject(err);
});
```

```html
Recommended using Sequelize's own operators
```

```
var defered = Q.defer();
const offset = queryString.offset * queryString.limit;
const limit = queryString.limit;
var queryWhere = { class_id: { $ne: null }, section_id: { $ne: null } };
var searchClass = {};
var searchSection = {};
if (queryString) {
    if (queryString.class && queryString.class !== "") {
       searchClass = { class_id: { $eq: queryString.class } };
    } else if (queryString.class && queryString.class === "") {
       searchClass = { class_id: { $ne: null } };
    }

if (queryString.section && queryString.section !== "") {
      searchSection = { section_id: { $eq: queryString.section } };
} else if (queryString.section && queryString.section === "") {
      searchSection = { section_id: { $ne: null } };
}
}

queryWhere = {
    $and: [[searchClass], [searchSection]]
};
const schoolDB = require("../../db/models/tenant")(schema);
const Student = schoolDB.model("Student");
Student.findAll({
   attributes: [
  "id",
  "first_name",
  "last_name",
  "profile_image_url",
  "roll_number",
  "emergency_contact_number"
],
offset: offset,
limit: limit,
where: queryWhere,
order: [["roll_number", "ASC"]]
})
.then(result => {
  defered.resolve(result);
})
.catch(err => {
  defered.reject(err);
});
```

Comment: Try adding a description of what you are doing and why.